# OpenGL ES2: syntax error when using "layout" keyword in vertex shader(iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, glsl, shader

I'm new to iPhone OpenGL ES development. When I try to specify the location of a vertex attribute using the 'layout' keyword, the compiler complains there is a syntax error. Am I using it wrong? or the compiler doesn't support the keyword? I know there are other ways to specify the location, but I wonder why this one doesn't work for me.
BTW, I'm using OpenGLES2.0 API.

the vertex shader is:

```c
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

vertex shader compile log:

> ```
> 2019-12-25 10:47:48.518110+0800 OpenGLESTest[14556:1063881] compile vertex shader error!
> 2019-12-25 10:47:48.518284+0800 OpenGLESTest[14556:1063881] compile stage info log 
> ERROR: 0:1: 'layout' : syntax error: syntax error
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenGL ES 2.0 and [OpenGL ES Shading Language 1.00](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf) neither [`Layout Qualifiers`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)) not the keyword `in` is supported.
If you want to use layout qualifiers, you've to switch to OpenGL ES 3.00 and [OpenGL ES Shading Language 3.00](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf). See [Khronos OpenGL ES Registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_es.php).

Correct GLSL ES 1.00 vertex shader (corresponding to OpenGL ES 2.00):

```c
#version 100

attribute vec3 position;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```